# mobile detection full site link

Tags: javascript, mobile

When using the JS code for mobile browser detection - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com How can I add a "View Full Site" button to my mobile page?

I found this:

[Link on site: http://example.com?fullsite=true'>Link to full site]

then add this to the end of the detect mobile browsers js.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
    return; // skip redirect
}
```

I am pretty new to JS so need a bit of help on how to add this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for you:

What you will need:

- JQuery 1.7+
- Modernizr

Get the Code from [this](https://github.com/chrismorata/Responsive-View-Full-Site) Github repo. And ad it to your website.

Ad the following button.

```
<div class="rwd-display-options">
<span id="view-full" class="rwd-display-option">View Full Site</span>
</div>
```

You can get more information and support from [the website of the developer](http://creativeandcode.com/responsive-view-full-site/)

Comment: I am using the Js script from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com - I think your method would work if i were using a viewport script only. ??

Comment: Yes it works if  you only use a viewport script.  I like method with the viewport more because it's very easy...

Comment: It is easy but is reliant on screen resolutions.. not very future proof. But it may well be the only option..